# How to make editText remember user input and make it appear below in dialog next time user presses the editText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an idea on how to implement it, but wondering whether it would be an optimal solution.
So I want to save the user input in variable and pass it to a dialog in editText's textChanged listener event. Would it be an optimal solution?

Comment: It seems correct. You can store the variable in activity (fragment). Then while dialog creation you pass it to dialog, add text watcher, which updates the variable in activity

Comment: Use `AutoCompleteTextView`.